# How to know the value of pk in django models

Tags: python, django, docker, django-models

i am learning Django right now and i want to get a table with my "database" and the id/pk of each row of info. right now i have this:

Model:

```
class Car(HistoryBase):
plate = models.CharField(max_length=6, default='', verbose_name="Placa")
year = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True, default='', verbose_name="Año del auto")
model = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, default='', verbose_name="Modelo del auto")
brand = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, default='', verbose_name="Marca del auto")
color = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, default='', verbose_name="Color del auto")
```

Form:

```
from ..core.forms import BootstrapModelForm
from .models import Car


class CarModelForm(BootstrapModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Car
      fields = '__all__'
```

View:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import Car
from .forms import CarModelForm

class CarDetailView(CreateView):
template_name = "cars_detail.html"
http_method_names = [u'get', u'post', ]
form_class = CarModelForm
model = Car
success_url = '/autos/{}'

def _get_car(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        pk = int(self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return Car.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Exception:
        return None
```

Template:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-title"><h2>Listado de Autos</h2></div>
      <hr>
      <table id="tabla" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Numero</th>
            <th>Placa</th>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Modelo</th>
            <th>Color</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for object in object_list %}
          <tr>
            **<td>{{ object.object_instance.pk }}</td>**
            <td>{{ object.plate }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ object.brand }}</td>
            <td>{{ object.model }}</td>
            <td>{{ object.color }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

when i go to the chrome to see the table the "numero" or ID column is blank, some help please :)

Comment: It is just `{{ object.pk }}`. I'm curious why you think it would be `object.object_instance.pk`?

Comment: But not much of this makes sense. That view doesn't seem to have anything to do with the template; it doesn't send a list of cars, and the `_get_car` method is pointless and never called.

Comment: You named your view `CarDetailView` but it is a CreateView. Better name it `CarCreateView`.

Comment: @guillermochamorro: no it is probably the other way around: it looks like a *list view*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pk` is just an attribute of a `Model` instance, so you can write it like:

```
<td>{{ object.pk }}</td>
```

The object is after all an model instance. The `.pk` attribute is thus something that is added by the "*Django logic*".

That being said, you probably should fix your Django `CreateView` (which is strange as well, since this looks more like a `ListView`). Here the `_get_car(..)` is - on first sight - never called. The logic all happens since you wrote `model=...`.